What's the general algorithm for subdividing a plane by a circle and displacing up or down?
I'd like to paint hills/valleys onto my plane.
I have a plane (currently drawn in wireframe mode) which I am determining it's hitpoint by raycasting. I'm then drawing a circle at that location.
Question is, on mouse click, how would I subdivide the plane into smaller triangles which form a circle which I can then raise up or down to produce hills/valleys? Is there an algorithm for this?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

In general, modifying geometry in real time is difficult. Here's one common alternative approach:

Start with a tessellated grid of triangles, instead of a single quad.
Also create a single-channel render target containing one pixel for each vertex in your grid. This is a height-map.
In the vertex shader sample the height-map (at a UV coordinate calculated from the X and Y coordinates of the vertex) and add the height value (possibly scaled by a parameter) onto the Z coordinate of the vertex to make it move up / down.
To modify the heights, you can render a circle (or any other shape) into the height-map render target.

Note that because this is a GPU driven approach, you may also want to do the ray casting (also known as "picking") for the mouse on the GPU. That is usually done by reading back a value from the depth buffer. You could also transfer the necessary data back to the CPU and do the calculations there, but that can be slow.
Note that because of the high geometric detail, this can be expensive to render, especially for a large terrain. There are various ways to apply variable levels of geometric detail on top of that basic approach to improve performance. Here's a link to one example of that: https://victorbush.com/2015/01/tessellated-terrain/

Using a render target as a heightmap is a good way to go. If the user later wants to add dynamic subdivision rather than one pre-tesselated grid, they can take a quadtree approach: Start with one quad covering the whole heightmap, and compute the maximum error (how far does a value in the heightmap deviate from the height of the quad). Any time that error is above a threshold tolerance, subdivide the quad into four, and recurse on each child. In the end you get bigger quads/triangles in smooth regions and more, smaller ones in bumpy regions, using the same core painting approach Adam suggests.
